# SAS Enterprise guide migration from 4.3 to 5.1

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sas, add-in, visual-studio-addins, enterprise-guide

I created 9 add-ins in a project in VS 2008. And I builded project so VS created a .dll file. Using this way

```
Tools -> Add-in -> Add-in Manager -> Browse -> (choose .dll which I created at VS 2008)
```

when I add add-in's .dll file to SAS Enterprise Guide 4.3, it works perfectly, EG 4.1 recognizes all of add-ins in .dll. But when I add add-in's .dll file to SAS Enterprise Guide 5.1, SAS EG 5.1 shows only 8 add-ins. It doesn't recognize one of them.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's possible it's not compatible with 5.1 - from 4.3 to 5.1 (to 6.1) they made significant changes to EG.

Comment: If there are significant changes between these versions, I want to find where the problem occurs in new version. So change my code immidiately.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know much about add-in development for EG.  I would recommend posting on communities.sas.com if you don't get any traction here; Chris Hemedinger and a few others who do EG add-in development post regularly there.

Comment: You can follow the issue by this link : https://communities.sas.com/thread/51654

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because SAS EG 4.1 like a special created Add-Ins based on the Microsoft .Net Fremawork in version 1.1. This version with new Wendows 7 and EG 5.1 is not compatible. 
Projects that consists Add-Ins cannot automatically migrate. I think you should more concentrate on the ability to work for your program in new EG 5.1 than try to trasfer Addi-Ins. For this you can use SAS standart tools.